# error when using load-theme from emacs

Tags: emacs

I am running emacs 24.4.50.1 and when I add the following line

```
(load-theme 'wombat t)
```

I get the following error when I try and start emacs:

> Fatal error 6: Abort trap^[[>0;95;c/usr/local/bin/emacs: line 2:   676
>   Abort trap: 6
>   /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw "$@"

The same thing happens when I enter the command:

```
load-them <RET> wombat
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed this via homebrew:

```
brew install emacs --HEAD --use-git-head --cocoa --with-gnutls
```

Which installed version 24.4.50.1

I uninstalled this and installed version 24.3.1 and the problem went away so it seems the issues is with the HEAD of emacs.

Comment: That kind of issues appears once in a while in the Emacs trunk, the build can fail, Emacs may crash on startup, etc. I'm syncing with the latest and greatest once a week and I've disabled themes for now...